# Adobe's BAAAM Tool showing Overflow Error

Tags: adobe, bulk

I am trying to get the list of segments using Adobe's Bulk Management tool from Adobe Audience Manager. However, I am encountering an error which says "Error while performing the requested action. Overflow."
I have tried getting list of segments using Data Source IDs but encountering the same error.
There are only 2665 segments and an overflow should not occur. Can anybody please help me how to resolve it?